# Is there a way to grab a screenshot by manually entering coordinates in OSX

Tags: macos, coordinates, screenshot, osx-yosemite

When I am grabbing a screenshot in OSX (Yosemite) by using `Cmd + Shift + 4`, I notice that the coordinates are displayed beside the crosshair. Now, I would like to take an accurate series of screenshots between the same coordinates. Is there a way to capture a screenshot based on coordinates we give?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use the built-in `screencapture` program like this:

```
screencapture -R10,10,100,100 file.png
```

where 10,10 are the [x,y] coordinates of the top-left corner and 100,100 are the width and height.

It is not documented in the manpages :-(

Comment: This is great! Thank you. However, it seems like I can only do this after capturing a screenshot. I presume there is not direct way to capture a screenshot of a box specified by its coordinates, then.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - this is not AFTER the screen capture - this IS the actual screen capture. The parameters do specify the coordinates of the capture. Maybe click `edit` under your original question and put the sort of command you want to use and what it should do.