# How to take screenshot of a program in linux, with python3?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, imagemagick

How can I create a screenshot of a specific program such as a text editor with a basic hello world printing script in linux. I've looked at Imagemagick but that only seems to do the whole window or coordinates of a window.

I'm either looking for a way to get the coordinates of a program, then pass that to imagemagick or a way to do it simply with a python module.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32496672/2836621 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/74325989/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think scrot is best for you.

```
scrot -u
```

this will get the screen shot of the current active window.
if you need some time and get the screenshot then you can do like this like

```
sleep 2; scrot -u
```

this command will wait for 2 sec then take the screenshot.

NOTE: This command only take the current window which is focused on.